# Why did null values appear inside the first line of solr.log

Tags: logging, indexing, solr

My code is looking for words "Read import_aml_entities.properties" inside solr.log by using grep command and then writing the result in a txt file. This has worked previously. However, recently, I have encountered a problem where the result in the txt file shows: Binary file solr.log matches. I checked solr.log and found out the it has NULL values at the first line and it made solr.log a binary file. I wanted to know why this happened? Is this a bug of the solr system?

Image of solr.log:
[NULL Values inside solr.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lk6D4.jpg)

I am doing a full import when this happened. I have a separate shell script calling the curl command to do full import.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it seems that this happens:

> If there is a NULL character anywhere in the file, grep will consider it as a binary file.

Source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/19911/426478 - user bbaja2

I cant figure out why this happens but to let your grep command work the solution is to use the option "-a" like

```
grep "Read import_aml_entities.properties" -a solr.log
```

Source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/226980/426478 - user Plouff